# Can MVC3 perform the job of IIS URL Rewrite module for my Angular6 App

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, angular6, url-rewrite-module

I am working on an Angular (6) app which sits within an existing MVC3 application. I.e. /MVC/App is my angular app. I have configured it using IIS Url Rewrite so that any request to "/Mvc/App" is forwarded to index.html page, just as described here, to make sure angular routing works:
https://blog.angularindepth.com/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7

It all works, but it poses a requirement for existing clients that they will have to install IIS Rewrite Module as a prerequisite. So I am looking for an alternative and since we already have MVC3 I wanted to know if it is possible to achieve this using MVC3 routing.

Can we achieve what the IIS ReWrite is doing here to ensure that all requests are served up to the Index.html page with the child routes so that angular routing works as expected?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by creating a controller with action and a routemap that maps any route starting with /Mvc/app to that action as below:
           context.MapRoute(
                "AngularAppRoute",
                "app/{*pathInfo}",
                new { controller = "SpaApp", action = "Index", pathInfo = "" }
            );

I had to make sure that the Index action's view does not have any master page and it's content was set to the same as the Index.html file generated by ng-build.